# error: conversion from ‘unique_ptr<GreenStack,default_delete<GreenStack>>’ to non-scalar type ‘unique_ptr<Stack,default_delete<Stack>>’ requested

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I am trying to assign a `unique_ptr` holding a derived class pointer to a `unique_ptr` holding a base class pointer. However, I am receiving the following error:

> error: conversion from ‘unique_ptr<GreenStack,default_delete<GreenStack>>’ to non-scalar type ‘unique_ptr<Stack,default_delete<Stack>>’ requested

Code snippet is below.

```
class GreenStack;    
class Stack {
 public:
  explicit Stack(double initial_weight) : weight_(initial_weight) {}
  static std::unique_ptr<Stack> makeGreenStack(double initial_weight)
  {
    //std::unique_ptr<Stack> box =  std::make_unique<Stack>(initial_weight);
    std::unique_ptr<Stack> green_box_01 =  std::make_unique<GreenStack>(initial_weight);
    return std::move(green_box_01);
  }
  bool operator<(const Stack& rhs) const { return weight_ < rhs.weight_; }
  virtual ~Stack() = default;

 protected:
  double weight_;
};

class GreenStack:public Stack
{
  public:
  explicit GreenStack(double initial_weight): Stack(initial_weight){}
  ~GreenStack() = default;

};
```

Please guide to resolve this error.

Comment: At the time the compiler sees the conversion from `std::unique_ptr<GreenStack>` to `std::unique_ptr<Stack>` (inside `makeGreenStack`) you have not yet told the compiler that `GreenStack` derives from `Stack`.

Comment: Side note: It's rare to have a case where a base class explicitly knows about a derived class, and even then it's kind of "dirty". Here it's not necessary. `makeGreenStack` could be a free function defined after `GreenStack`. This solves all of your problems and is more ideologically correct.

Comment: Side note: See [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) for a good case that abstracts knowledge about the derived class from the base class while still allowing the base class to use the derived class. Doesn't help here, but it's a cool trick for when you do need it.

Comment: Side note: `return std::move(green_box_01);` is a pessimistic move.  It prevents return value optimization.  Change it to `return green_box_01;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `Stack::makeGreenStack(double)` **after** defining `GreenStack` to be derived from `Stack`.

The compiler will then know that a `std::unique_ptr<Stack>` can be initialized from a `std::unique_ptr<GreenStack>`

```
class GreenStack;    
class Stack {
 public:
  explicit Stack(double initial_weight) : weight_(initial_weight) {}
  static std::unique_ptr<Stack> makeGreenStack(double initial_weight);

  bool operator<(const Stack& rhs) const { return weight_ < rhs.weight_; }
  virtual ~Stack() = default;

 protected:
  double weight_;
};

class GreenStack:public Stack
{
  public:
  explicit GreenStack(double initial_weight): Stack(initial_weight){}
  ~GreenStack() = default;

};

std::unique_ptr<Stack> Stack::makeGreenStack(double initial_weight)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Stack> green_box_01 =  std::make_unique<GreenStack>(initial_weight);
    return green_box_01;
}
```